# Dotted border - evenly spaced dots

Tags: css, border, spacing

I'm trying (and failing) to produce a circle
with completely evenly spaced dots on the border.
Making a nicely rounded dotted border is no problem.
But the dots don't quite space out just right.
I've tried many different combinations of div sizes,
dot (border) sizes, radius sizes, etc. There's always
those two dots at the top that aren't spaced evenly.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
}

.vertz {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.horz {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: auto;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
}

.dots {
  border: rgba(3, 79, 132, 0.75) dotted 5px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  -o-border-radius: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertz horz dots"></div>
```